# For loop stacks and external functions without repeating popleft()

Tags: python, list, for-loop, stack, deque

I'm trying to define a function with two stacks (collection deque stacks) where items from the first
stack is popped and appended to an empty stack and then both stacks are sent to an external function.
I need to repeat this process twice as follows but do not want to repeat the code so I wonder if there is some efficient way to do this with a while loop - break statement or iterator?

```
import collections
from collections import deque

sentence = [0,1,2,3,4]

stack1 = deque(sentence)  # contains sentence
stack2 = deque([])          # empty, awaiting items from stack1

for i in range(0,len(sentence)): 
    stack1.popleft(i)     # pop first item to the left from stack1;0 ([**0**,1,2,3,4])
    stack2.append(i)      # append it to stack 2; stack2 = ([0])

    function(stack1, stack2)   #run stack1 and stack2 in external functions
   # Repeating
    stack1.popleft(i) again    #pop (only) once more from stack1; 1 ([**1**,2,3,4])
    stack2.append(i) again     # append it to stack2; stack2 = ([0, 1])

   function (stack1, stack2)   # run the external function again
```

ENDFOR - end function, no more rounds

Comment: Why not just define a function that takes in the two stacks and `i`, and does exactly what you just did twice. So, in essence an external function call.

Comment: The stack content effects the value in the function so I could add the stack1.popleft() and stack2.append() to a function as you say but I would have to repeat the function that takes the stacks, function(stack1, stack2), once more.

Comment: `deque.popleft()` doesn't take any parameters. Do you perhaps mean to do `stack2.append(stack1.popleft())`?

Comment: `stack1` is going to run out of stuff to pop if you do this.

Comment: I didn't know stack1.popleft() could be passed in stack2.append(), has to be regulated with a while loop, one is posted below which works great for the two rounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a simple function to handle this:

```
from collections import deque

sentence = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

stack1 = deque(sentence)
stack2 = deque([])


print(stack1, stack2)


def do_it(st1, st2):
    item = st1.popleft()
    st2.append(item)

while stack1:
    do_it(stack1, stack2)
    # Do some stuff here
    do_it(stack1, stack2)

print(stack1, stack2)
```

Output:

```
(deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), deque([]))
(deque([]), deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```